# TPL wait curiosity

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I was playing around with **TPL**, and find out something that is very strange.
Code waits for tasks to end, and doing this dummy test, found out that a couple of task were executed after the `Wait` call. I'm I missing something, or this is a TPL problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task tareas = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Start process");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
            {
                var n = i.ToString();
                tareas = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var random = new Random();
                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(200, 500));

                    Console.WriteLine("Task completed: " + n);
                });
            }

            tareas.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Process end");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start process
Task completed: 4
Task completed: 3

...

End process
Task completed: 3996
Task completed: 3991
Task completed: 3993
```

Comment: You start 4000 tasks but only wait for the last.

Comment: BTW, your way of using `Random` is not actually very random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `tareas.Wait();` only waits **for the last task you created to complete**. As your tasks complete in a random amount of time, it's perfectly normal that some tasks are not yet completed once the last one your created completes.

Here's an example of what could happen:

```
Task 1 created
Task 2 created
Task 3 created
Task 4 created

Task 1 completed
Task 3 completed

Wait for task 4 completion
Task 4 completed

// task 2 executed during more time than other 
// tasks because of the random value the thread waited
Task 2 completed
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you're waiting on only a single task, the last one scheduled.

Tasks scheduled on the default `TaskScheduler` use the thread pool to execute the work items as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx). With this scheduler, ordering is not guaranteed. The framework will attempt to balance the queues running on each thread in the pool, but it is possible (and not uncommon) that the queue in which the last scheduled task is put will finish running through all its tasks before the other queues.

This is without even considering the `Wait`. Check out the section labeled “Task Inlining” in the document I linked – if a task is being waited on, the thread executing the wait can say 'well, I can't do anything until this task is complete, let me see if I can go ahead and execute it myself'. In that case, the task gets removed from the thread pool queue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

taereas will contain reference to your last created thread, so treas.Wait() will wait only for last thread to finish, so other threads may run even after your last thread has finished.